# Gram-Schmidt Process to find an orthonormal basis for a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, orthonormal

> By using the Gram-Schmidt Process find an orthonormal basis for the
>   column space of the matrix:
>
> $$A=\begin{pmatrix}0 & -3 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 1 & -3 &
>  0\end{pmatrix}$$
>
> Note: The basis vectors should be normalised so that the third entry
>   in each column vector is positive.

Having tried the question I obtained a basis consisting of:

$$x_1 = [0, 1, 1]$$
$$x_2 = [-3, 3/2, -3/2]$$
$$x_3 = [1, 1/2, -1/2]$$

The note part of the question confuses me however as I fail to see how this will make the basis of positive.

Help is very much appreciated.

Comment: If $b_1,...,b_n$ is an orthonormal basis, then so are all the $2^n$ combinations $\pm b_1,...,\pm b_n$. So, you should choose $x_1,-x_2,-x_3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your vectors are neither orthogonal ($x_2 \cdot x_3 = -1.5)$, nor normal.

The note to your question points to the choice, given a normal vector $n$, of choosing either $n$ or $-n$ as normal.

How to orthonormalize:

We could start with $x_1$ and keep it as first vector of the new base, $x_1' = x_1$.

We want to end up with normal vectors as well, so it is better to do the normalization now.
The second vector is the second given vector without the parts in direction of the first new base vector:
\begin{align}
x_1'' 
&= \frac{x_1'}{\sqrt{x_1' \cdot x_1'}} = \frac{x_1}{\sqrt{x_1 \cdot x_1}} \\
x_2' &= x_2 - (x_1'' \cdot x_2) x_1'' \\
x_2'' &= \frac{x_2'}{\sqrt{x_2' \cdot x_2'}} \\
x_3' &= x_3 - (x_1'' \cdot x_3) x_1''- (x_2'' \cdot x_3) x_2'' \\
x_3'' &= \frac{x_3'}{\sqrt{x_3' \cdot x_3'}} \\
\end{align}
Thus here
\begin{align}
x_1'' &= (0, 1/\sqrt{2}, 1/\sqrt{2}) \\
x_2' &= (3, -3/2, 3/2) \\
x_2'' &= \sqrt{\frac{2}{27}}(3,-3/2, 3/2) \\
x_3' &= (2/3, 2/3, -2/3) \\
x_3'' &= \frac{\sqrt{3}}{2} (2/3, 2/3,-2/3) = (1/\sqrt{3},1/\sqrt{3},-1/\sqrt{3})
\end{align}
For the third vector we removed the parts in direction of the new first and second vector.

Only $x_3''$ has negative third component, so we choose
$$
x_3''' = - x_3'' = (-1/\sqrt{3},-1/\sqrt{3},/\sqrt{3})
$$

Comment: So I've miscalculated the vectors via the Gram-Schmit method and upon obtaining the correct ones I can simply take reverse its sign to ensure the third entry in each column is positive?

Comment: Yes. The only thing to watch out for is to flip the signs of all components of the vector, not just the third component.

Comment: Thanks you were very helpful and I understand what I've done wrong as well.